# how to use wget to download videos?

Tags: wget

I want to download videos from this link http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=106102064 
I don't know how to use wget to download the videos from this site. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

better still:

```
wget -c -O /pathtoLocalDirectory/choosefilename.extensionLike3gpORflvORmp4 "HerePutTheHyperlinkInsideInvertedCommasWithoutAnyExtraSpacesSay http://somesite.something.somemorethings.etc"
```

reasons:

- `-c`: 
  if connection to server is broken before completion of your download then wget resumes from previously downloaded position, otherwise it wastes away what was already downloaded and has to restart from zero
- `-O`: 
  allows you to choose the location and filename of your choice in your computer

Comment: Hi akhil, welcome to askubuntu! This is a valid answer. Just two things: 1) Keep the example command short. The way it is now is not very readable. 2) Put commands in [block format](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the file name as the parameter for 'wget'.

This works for me:

```
wget http://npteldownloads.iitm.ac.in/downloads_mp4/106102064/lec01.mp4
```