# How can i download all videos (only videos) from a website using wget?

Tags: wget

This question is already asked before in "askubuntu" and "stack overflow" but no one answers best fit for question.
I want to download only videos from a website and not any other file.
HELP me ..
[how to use wge to download videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338250/how-to-use-wget-to-download-videos)

Comment: In the first answer of the question mentioned look closely it is mentioned *extension of file*. So you can use mp4, 3gp, flv, extensions for **video** to download.

Comment: Can you give a sample web site?

Comment: I have already done all commands from previous given answers but it starts downloading whole website not video >>> so, please give me a better command which best fits for my question and suppose the website is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/